# Address for a 2/3d array in c

Tags: c, arrays

So, if I have this in C,

```
int a[50];
```

and I use `a`, it actually points to the address of the first element of the array.

But, if I have `int b[10][10]` , and I use `b` or `b[0]` , to what it will point to?

Secondly, if I do,

```
`&a[0]`
```

this basically gives me the address of the first element, but if I do, `&a` , what does this mean actually? And also operations like, `&a + 1` . Basically, are we calculating the address of the address of the first element of the array?

Or for that matter if I have a 3d array, `int c[10][10][10]`, then what does, `c` means? To which element will it point to? Or, if I do, `c[0]+1` , to what part of the array will this point to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an array such as

```
int a[X][Y];
```

Then using just `a` will have it decay to a pointer to the first element in the first array.

The expression `&a[0]` will return a pointer to the first array, hich then decays to a pointer to the first element. So both `a` and `&a[0]` (as well as plain `a[0]` and of course `&a[0][0]`) will all point to the same thing. The difference is in the types:

- `a` is an array of arrays of integers, which decays to a pointer to an array of integers
- `a[0]` is an array of integers, which decays to a pointer to an integer
- `&a[0]` is a pointer to an array of integers
- `&a` is a pointer to an array of arrays of integers
- `&a[0][0]` is a pointer to an integer

All the expressions above, will either point to, or decay to a pointer to, the very same element: The first integer in the first array (i.e `a[0][0]`).

For completeness sake:

- `a[0][0]` is an integer, the very first in the very first array.

---

Since `&a` is a pointer to an array of array of integers, adding one (i.e `&a + 1`) will add the size of the array of array integers, in other words the expression returns a pointer to `a + sizeof(a)`, which is a pointer to one beyond the end of `a`. In more other words, it's the same as `(&a)[1]`.

---

More curiosity: For a generic pointer or array `p`, doing `p[x]` is the same as doing `p + x`. And now for the weird part: Due to the [communicative nature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) of [addition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition), the expression `p + x` is equal to `x + p`, which in turn leads to `p[x]` is equal to `x[p]`.

---

For the dereferencing:

- `*a` decays `a` to a pointer to an array of arrays of integers, so `*a` is an array of integers (i.e. `a[0]`)
- `*a[0]` since the indexing operator has higher [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than the dereference operator, you first have `a[0]` which is an array of integers, the dereference then decays it to a pointer to the first element of that array which it the dereferences (i.e. it's the same as `a[0][0]`)

Comment: But, what will `a[0]` mean? Or what does `&a` means?

Comment: And, if I do `&a+1`, what will this point to actually? If we assume the starting address of `a[0][0]` as 125, then what address will `&a+1` will point to? i.e. if we take X and Y as `2` and `3` respectively.

Comment: And, I have one more doubt. If I do, `printf("%d\n",*a)` , what will this do? Wont this be incorrect? It should give out an error, right?
Because, `*a` basically will point to the first array of integers without specifiying which element to print.

Comment: @bjohn Edited answer again, added a couple of dereference examples to the bottom

Comment: Perfect. But the statement `printf("%d\n",*a)` in itself wont be valid, right? It will give a compilation error?

Comment: @bjohn You probably don't get an error, but a warning, because the [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) format code `"%d"` is to print `int`, and `*a` is a pointer. If you want to print a pointer you should use the format `"%p"` (and also cast the pointer to `void *` to be correct, even though it will probably work without the casting as well).

Answer (score 0):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operator, or is a string literal being used to initialize an array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first M-element array.

Given the following declaration:

```
T a[N][M];
```

the *expression* `a` has type "`N`-element array of `M`-element arrays of `T`"; by the rule above, it will decay to an expression of type "pointer to `M`-element array of `T`", or `T (*)[M]`, and the value will be the address of the first element of that array.

The following table shows the types and meanings of various expressions involving `a`:

```
Expression    Type          Decays to    Meaning
----------    ----          ---------    -------
         a    T [N][M]      T (*)[M]     Points to first M-element array
        &a    T (*)[N][M]                Points to entire NxM array
        *a    T [M]         T *          Points to first element of first array
      a[i]    T [M]         T *          Points to first element of i'th array
     &a[i]    T (*)[M]                   Points to i'th M-element array
     *a[i]    T                          Value of first element of i'th array
   a[i][j]    T                          Value of j'th element of i'th array
  &a[i][j]    T *                        Points to j'th element of i'th array
```

Since the address of the first element is the same as the address of the array itself, all of the expressions `a`, `*a`, `&a`, `a[0]`, `&a[0]`, and `&a[0][0]` yield the same *value*, but the *types* of the expressions are different.

This pattern extends to higher-dimensioned arrays.  I'd draw out an example for a 3-d array, but I'm typing this on an iPad, which has already slowed me down considerably.